# Redirect cout if it is used in a function in another file

Tags: c++, cout, clion

I'm using Mac OS X (El Captain) and CLion and I've created a project that contains the following files:

1) **main.cpp**:

```
#include <fstream>
std::ifstream cin("/Users/alekscooper/Dropbox/96 - CLion Dummy Project/input.txt");
std::ofstream cout("/Users/alekscooper/Dropbox/96 - CLion Dummy Project/output.txt");

#include "foo.h"

using std::endl;

int main() {
    int x, y, z;
    cin >> x >> y >> z;
    cout << x + y + z << " Test sum is printed" << endl;
    foo();
    return 0;
}
```

2) **foo.h**

```
void foo();
```

3) **one_more_file.cpp**

```
#pragma once

#include <iostream>

void foo() {
    std::cout << "I'm a foo" << std::endl;
}
```

**What I expect my project:**

- to contain multiple *.cpp and *.h files
- to print from all the functions in all the files into `.../output.txt`

**What the problem is**:

While the `cout` in the main.cpp does print the test sum and the message in `.../output.txt`, the `cout` in the `foo()` function prints 'I'm a foo' into the console window. In other words, the input in the `foo()` function does not get redirected into `.../output.txt`. Why is that and how can I fix that?

Comment: This is not a question about how to redirect cout in general, this is a question about how to redirect cout if it is in another file in a multiple source file project, it's a question about an unexpected behavior of code, not a 'do it for me I'm too lazy' question.

Comment: Your `cout` in main and `std::cout` in foo are two totally different streams. They just have similar names. To be more flexible about where the output goes you could have `void foo(std::ostream& output)` and use `output <<` for all output. Then the caller of foo can decide where the output goes by passing a suitable stream.